# I want to take "terminal" in "Atom"

Tags: terminal

I want to take "terminal" in "Atom", but many of errors happen to me. Could you help?

Code:

```
$ apm install term2
Installing term2 to /User/.atom/packages ✗

> pty.js@0.2.13 install /private/var/folders/bh/qqktv0_n49vc585f8dn7hq600000gn/T/apm-install-dir-115721-23811-m9y2he/node_modules/term2/node_modules/pty.js
> node-gyp rebuild

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/pty/src/unix/pty.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/pty.node

ld: library not found for -lgcc_s.10.5
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Release/pty.node] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/Downloads/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.4.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/Users/Downloads/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /private/var/folders/bh/qqktv0_n49vc585f8dn7hq600000gn/T/apm-install-dir-115721-23811-m9y2he/node_modules/term2/node_modules/pty.js
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.35
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Darwin 14.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users//Downloads/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/bin/node" "/Users/Downloads/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "--globalconfig" "/Users//.atom/.apm/.apmrc" "--userconfig" "/Users//.atom/.apmrc" "install" "/private/var/folders/bh/qqktv0_n49vc585f8dn7hq600000gn/T/d-115721-23811-j9f77o/package.tgz" "--target=0.22.0" "--arch=x64"
npm ERR! node v0.10.35
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! pty.js@0.2.13 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the pty.js@0.2.13 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the pty.js package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls pty.js
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /private/var/folders/bh/qqktv0_n49vc585f8dn7hq600000gn/T/apm-install-dir-115721-23811-m9y2he/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific on your question?